# Roblox Motion Blur script

Tags: lua, blur, motion, roblox

I am trying to find out a way to add motion blur to my relaxation simulator game. I have been trying to find a result that will work for the past few days, and I have had no luck. Like my last Roblox help post, I got negative reviews, so let me be more specific; It has to be a script of course. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a link to a tutorial or something among the lines of that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply googling "Roblox motion blur script" yields many results that may be helpful to you, such as:

[This script](https://www.roblox.com/library/10811550/Fixed-Motion-Blur-script), [this script](https://www.roblox.com/library/7072747/Motion-Blur-Script-Giver), [this script](https://www.roblox.com/library/420041790/motion-blur-script), and [this script](https://www.roblox.com/library/414459102/Motion-Blur).

If these results from the Roblox script library aren't what you're looking for, try looking into how to utilize Roblox's shaders to create the effect you're looking for.

If you need help getting started in Lua (which is the programming language used within Roblox) I would check out a tutorial similar to [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLwYJY8KSgc) that explains Lua and how to use it within Roblox.

Answer (score 0):

Something you should know is that, it is impossible (atleast in 2018, maybe in a future) to create good motion blur in roblox. Roblox has not made a Instance that can make your game have Motion Blur, sadly.

There is a way to create something close, but it doens't look too good.
That is using BlurEffects for it, but again, it doens't look good.

Sadly, until roblox decides to add more effects, we will not be able to add Motion Blur to our games, but until then, we have the BlurEffects technique.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to solve this problem .....To blur the player screen there is an option or feature in lighting. Click the add "+" button in lighting menu. There are effects such as blur , depth of field . The blur option blurs the screen and depth of field would give better effects of blur in far or near objects.
Further reference:
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BlurEffect
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/post-processing-effects

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working script for Motion Blur in RBLX Studio.
First, go to StarterGUI and make a LocalScript.
Second, type this code in:

-- Variables

```
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local blurAmount = 10
local blurAmplifier = 5
local lastLookVector = camera.CFrame.LookVector

local motionProfile = Instance.new("BlurEffect", camera)

local runService = game:GetService("RunService")

workspace.Changed:Connect(function(property)
if property == "CurrentCamera" then
    print("Changed cam")
    camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
    
    if motionProfile and motionProfile.Parent then
        motionProfile.Parent = camera
    else
        motionProfile = Instance.new("BlurEffect", camera)
    end
end
```

end)

-- This is the main part of the motion blur(where all the blurring happens)

```
runService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    if not motionProfile or motionProfile.Parent == nil then
        motionProfile = Instance.new("BlurEffect", camera)
    end

    local magnitude = (camera.CFrame.LookVector - 
lastLookVector).magnitude
    motionProfile.Size = math.abs(magnitude)*blurAmount*blurAmplifier/2
    lastLookVector = camera.CFrame.LookVector
end)
```

- 

After that, it should be working fine.